# Apache Httpd as SSL termination proxy

Tags: ssl, https, apache

I would like to setup my Httpd as SSL termination proxy for my embedded Jetty.

I found this [article](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/08/08/setting-up-apache-as-a-ssl-front-end-for-play/), however, it is not working for my configurations. With the following in my httpd-vhosts.conf, I can access `http://mysite:9023` by `http://app.mysite`. However, I am not able to access `http://mysite:9023` by `https://app.mysite`.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName app.mysite
    ServerAlias www.app.mysite
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
        AddDefaultCharset Off
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://mysite:9023/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://mysite:9023/
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName app.mysite
    ServerAlias www.app.mysite
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile    "C:\apache\httpd\conf\server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:\apache\httpd\conf\server.key"
    <Location />
        SSLRequireSSL
    </Location>
   ProxyPass / http://mysite:9023/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://mysite:9023/
</VirtualHost>
```